# google Script insert as HTML

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

If I have the string:

```
var text = "Altman, R. (1992). Sound space. In R. Altman (Ed.), <em>Sound Theory Sound Practice</em> (pp. 46–64). New York: Routledge.";
```

How can I insert this into Google Docs with the required italics intact?

```
var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
cursor.insertText('here: ' + text);
```

Inserts the text as is (without displaying italics and showing the `<em>...</em>`).

A few people have asked similar questions here without success mostly getting answers that relate to creating a new document using the Drive service (I want to insert HTML text anywhere in an existing document).

I've come across intriguing snippets such as:

```
var text = Utilities.newBlob("").setDataFromString(response.bibEntry, "UTF-8").setContentType("text/html");
```

or:

```
var text = doGet('<b>Hello, world!</b>');
function doGet(text) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(text);
}
```

But these appear to return objects which I've no idea how to use – trying to use insertText(text), I get 'Blob' and 'HtmlOutput' respectively.

Answer (score 2):

I've taken what Rubén has provided above and bits and pieces from elsewhere to come up with a reasonably flexible way to convert HTML styling on external text for insertion at the cursor position in a google document. The caveat is that you need to know precisely the HTML tags that are in the external text (in my case, I do). This code does the italics plus a few other tags, deals with nested and multiple tags, and deletes the HTML code. For fun, I've added in HREF handling. I'm sure it can be improved and/or made more efficient (e.g. I'd love to know how to get away with just the one `regExp()`, for example) – how can it be improved?

```
var regexpItalics = RegExp(/(<em>)(.*?)(<\/em>)/, 'g');
var regexpBold = RegExp(/(<strong>)(.*?)(<\/strong>)/, 'g');
var regexpUnderline = RegExp(/(<span style="text-decoration: underline;">)(.*?)(<\/span>)/, 'g');
var regexpSub = RegExp(/(<sub>)(.*?)(<\/sub>)/, 'g');
var regexpSup = RegExp(/(<sup>)(.*?)(<\/sup>)/, 'g');
var regexpHref = RegExp(/(<a class="rLink" href=".*>)(.*?)(<\/a>)/, 'g');
var deleteArray = [];
var i;
var text = "some text with <em>itali<strong>cs</em> and bold</strong>";

var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var cursor = document.getCursor();
var element = cursor.insertText(text);
var styles = ['italics', 'bold', 'underline', 'super', 'sub', 'href'];
for (i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
  insertHtmlText(element, text, styles[i]);
}
deleteArray.sort(function (b, a) {
  return a.end - b.end;
});
for(i = 0; i < deleteArray.length; i++) {
  element.editAsText().deleteText(deleteArray[i].start, deleteArray[i].end);
}

function insertHtmlText(element, text, style) {
  var i;
  var matches = [];
  var transformArray = [];

  switch (style) {
    case 'italics': 
      matches = [...text.matchAll(regexpItalics)];
      transformArray = findTags(matches);
      for(i = 0; i < transformArray.length; i++) {
        element.editAsText().setItalic(transformArray[i].textStart, transformArray[i].textEnd, true);
      }
      break;
    case 'bold': 
      matches = [...text.matchAll(regexpBold)];
      transformArray = findTags(matches);
      for(i = 0; i < transformArray.length; i++) {
        element.editAsText().setBold(transformArray[i].textStart, transformArray[i].textEnd, true);
      }
      break;
    case 'underline': 
      matches = [...text.matchAll(regexpUnderline)];
      transformArray = findTags(matches);
      for(i = 0; i < transformArray.length; i++) {
        element.editAsText().setUnderline(transformArray[i].textStart, transformArray[i].textEnd, true);
      }
      break;
    case 'super': 
      matches = [...text.matchAll(regexpSup)];
      transformArray = findTags(matches);
      for(i = 0; i < transformArray.length; i++) {
        element.editAsText().setTextAlignment(transformArray[i].textStart, transformArray[i].textEnd, DocumentApp.TextAlignment.SUPERSCRIPT);
      }
      break;
    case 'sub': 
      matches = [...text.matchAll(regexpSub)];
      transformArray = findTags(matches);
      for(i = 0; i < transformArray.length; i++) {
        element.editAsText().setTextAlignment(transformArray[i].textStart, transformArray[i].textEnd, DocumentApp.TextAlignment.SUBSCRIPT);
      }
      break;
    case 'href': 
      matches = [...text.matchAll(regexpHref)];
      transformArray = findTags(matches);
      for(i = 0; i < transformArray.length; i++) {
        element.editAsText().setLinkUrl(transformArray[i].textStart, transformArray[i].textEnd, transformArray[i].capture);
      }
      break;
    default: 
      break; // Missing format
  }
}
function findTags(matches) {
  var openTagStart, openTagEnd, textStart, textEnd, closeTagStart, closeTagEnd;
  var transformArray = [];

  for (let match of matches) {
    openTagStart = match.index;
    openTagEnd = openTagStart + match[1].length - 1;
    textStart = openTagEnd + 1;
    textEnd = textStart + match[2].length - 1;
    closeTagStart = textEnd + 1;
    closeTagEnd = closeTagStart + match[3].length -1;
    transformArray.push({
      openTagStart: openTagStart,
      openTagEnd: openTagEnd,
      textStart: textStart,
      textEnd: textEnd,
      closeTagStart: closeTagStart,
      closeTagEnd: closeTagEnd,
      capture: match[2]
    });
    deleteArray.push({start: openTagStart, end: openTagEnd});
    deleteArray.push({start: closeTagStart, end: closeTagEnd});
  }
  return transformArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use HTML tags to format text in Google Docs on Google Apps Script, instead you should use the appropriated classes and methods. The following example use `setItalic(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, italic)` ;

```
function myFunction() {
  const text1 = "Altman, R. (1992). Sound space. In R. Altman (Ed.),";
  const text2 = "Sound Theory Sound Practice";
  const text3 = "(pp. 46–64). New York: Routledge.";
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const body = doc.getBody()
  body.setText([text1,text2,text3].join(" "))
  const start = text1.length + 1;
  const end = start + text2.length;
  body.editAsText().setItalic(start, end, true);
}
```

[image]

Resources

- [Extending Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides/editing-styling)
- [Class Text -> setItalic(italic)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setitalicitalic)
- [Class Text -> setAttributes(attributes)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setattributesattributes)

Comment: Thanks Rubén. I guess I need to hunt for HTML markup and break up my text then.

Comment: @MarkGrimshaw-Aagaard Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)